# r data.frame with json data

Tags: json, r

I have a data.frame which contains json data:

```
dat1 = data.frame(id = 001, name = "Mac", score = '{"math":5}', date = '{"date1":"2018-01-19","date2":"2018-01-20"}')
dat2 = data.frame(id = 002, name = "Eric", score = '{"math":7}', date = '{"date1":"2018-01-18","date2":"2018-01-20"}')
dat = rbind(dat1, dat2)
```

And I want to get the following data.frame:

```
#   id name   score.math     date.date1       date.date2
# 1  1  Mac       5          2018-01-19       2018-01-20
# 2  2 Eric       7          2018-01-18       2018-01-20
```

I want to use jsonlite::fromJSON first and rbind data then.

Comment: You can use `regexec` and `regmatches` to convert the date and score fields to the required object types. First, use `data.table::rbindlist(list(dat1, dat2), use.names = T, fill = T)` to get a combined data.table and then call the function on the two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
data.frame(c(dat[1:2], unlist(lapply(dat[3:4], function(x) 
    fromJSON(paste0("[", paste(x,  collapse=",\n"), "]"))),
            recursive = FALSE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#  id name score.math date.date1 date.date2
#1  1  Mac          5 2018-01-19 2018-01-20
#2  2 Eric          7 2018-01-18 2018-01-20
```